# Parsing a string for data sets

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a long string that contains sets of information that need to be separated/extracted for evaluation.

As a beginner programmer i am aware of various parsing operations like split() append() remove() etc - but i am struggling to come up with a logical method of combining them to extract the relevant data...

the long string...

```
"<Sets X="s"><B s="1" e="2176" t="-2.0774E4" r="1" /><B s="2177" e="8982" t="-1.8597E4" r="1" /><B s="8983" e="10393" t="-150.22" r="1" /></Sets>"
```

containing 3 sets of data that need to be stored as float values

[Set1] s=1 e=2176 t=-20774 r=1

[Set2] s=2177 e=8982 t=-18597 r=1

[Set3] s=8983 e=10393 t=-150.2 r=1

I would like for each set of data to be stored as a list

```
Set1 = [1,2176,-20774,1]
Set2 = [2177,8982,-18597,1]
Set3 = [2178,10393,-150.2,1]
```

*NB: the number of sets can vary*

Comment: ideal solution involves only the 'numpy' library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built-in [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library to extract the data from the xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = '<Sets X="s"><B s="1" e="2176" t="-2.0774E4" r="1" /><B s="2177" e="8982" t="-1.8597E4" r="1" /><B s="8983" e="10393" t="-150.22" r="1" /></Sets>'

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for b in tree.findall('.//B'):
     print map(float, itemgetter(*'setr')(b.attrib))
```

prints:

```
[1.0, 2176.0, -20774.0, 1.0]
[2177.0, 8982.0, -18597.0, 1.0]
[8983.0, 10393.0, -150.22, 1.0]
```

Comment: I'd make your print nicer and use `operator.itemgetter` - eg: `map(float, itemgetter(*'set')(b.attrib))` (but move out the getter to somewhere more appropriate)

Comment: cheers - ideally i don't want to have to import any more libraries (other than numpy)

Also, how are the output lists named in the code above? As there could be any number of sets they need to assigned list1, list2 etc...

Comment: @PeteLavelle it's a part of python's standard library.

Comment: Well, the power of Python comes from importing the appropriate libraries - whether they are builtin (such as `xml` and `operator`  or 3rd party `numpy`)... No one in their right mind would try to parse your string using normal `str` operations... It'd be painful, verbose, break easily and make people want to do bad things to you :) @PeteLavelle

Comment: no wonder i was having trouble coming up with a logical way of parsing the string with normal operations...

Comment: I am wondering why don't we have a special Jon Clements's badge for posting awesome comments :)

Answer (score 1):

**NB: this is an extension of a previous answer...**

*(props to @alecxe and @Jon Clements)*

In order to label each data set and store the results in an easily accessible format

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import operator

data = '<Sets X="s"><B s="1" e="2176" t="-2.0774E4" r="1" /><B s="2177" e="8982" t="-1.8597E4" r="1" /><B s="8983" e="10393" t="-150.22" r="1" /></Sets>'

dataDictionary = {}

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
setNumber = 0

for b in tree.findall('.//B'):
    setNumber = setNumber + 1
    dataSet = map(float, operator.itemgetter(*'setr')(b.attrib))
    dataDictionary[setNumber] = dataSet
    print "This is dataset " +str(setNumber)
    print dataSet

print ""
print "This is the Dictionary of datasets"
print dataDictionary
```

this results in the following output - which is easy to use for future operations :)

```
This is dataSet 1
[1.0, 2176.0, -20774.0, 1.0]
This is dataSet 2
[2177.0, 8982.0, -18597.0, 1.0]
This is dataSet 3
[8983.0, 10393.0, -150.22, 1.0]

This is the dataDictionary
{1: [1.0, 2176.0, -20774.0, 1.0], 2: [2177.0, 8982.0, -18597.0, 1.0], 3: [8983.0, 10393.0, -150.22, 1.0]}
```

Comment: Where does `burstNumber` come from - should that be `setNumber`? I'd also suggest that `for startNumber, b in enumerate(tree.findall('.//B'), start=1)` is an option to avoid manually incrementing your counter and using `print 'This is dataset', burstNumber` avoids the rather messy looking `str` call

Comment: @JonClements - you're right, it should've been setNumber. i'd changed the variable names to make it generic but missed that one out. now edited, cheers...